# reformat dataset from long to wide dataset

Tags: r, dataset, reformat

Hopefully, you can help my question.

I have dataset looks like this. There are 1500 rows.

```
+-------+---------+---------+--------+
| index |   item  |  taste  |  price |
+-------+---------+---------+--------+
|     1 |  orange |  low    |      3 |
|     1 | banana  |  medium |      4 |
|     1 |  pier   |  high   |      2 |
|     2 | apple   | medium  |      4 |
|     2 |  orange |  medium |      4 |
|     2 |  banana |  medium |      3 |
|   ... | ...     | ...     |    ... |
|  1500 | 1500    |  1500   |   1500 |
+-------+---------+---------+--------+
```

I use this code but got an error message:

```
library(data.table)

dcast(setDT(df), index ~ item, value.var = c("taste", "price"))
```

the error massage:

> Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In if (!(value.var %in% names(data))) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

this is the expected result that I want to get.

```
index, item, taste_orange,taste.banana, taste.pier, taste.apple, price_orange,price.banana, price.pier, price.apple, 
1, low,medium,high,0,3,4,2,0
2, medium,medium,0,medium,4,3,0,4
...,...,...,...,...,...,...,....,...
1500,1500, 1500,1500,1500,1500,1500,1500,1500
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the problem is your last line, the values are 1500 for all columns or is it just a way of telling us this is the last row?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a tidyverse approach you could do something like:

```
library(tidyverse)
test <- read_delim(file=clipboard(), 
  col_names=TRUE, delim=",", trim_ws=TRUE) ## copied your 6 lines of data into the clipboard
test %>% 
  gather(key, value, -item, -index) %>% 
  unite("names", item, key) %>% 
  spread(names, value) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with("_price")), as.numeric)
# A tibble: 2 x 9
  index apple_price apple_taste banana_price banana_taste orange_price
  <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>              <dbl> <chr>               <dbl>
1     1          NA NA                     4 medium                  3
2     2           4 medium                 3 medium                  4
# … with 3 more variables: orange_taste <chr>, pier_price <dbl>,
#   pier_taste <chr>
```

The "gather" command creates a "long" dataframe in which the "key" variable contains the type of information stored (i.e., taste and price), and the "value" variable contains the actual values; since the values are of different type, the numeric values are coerced into character. "unite" merges into a new column "names" the item description and the type of information. "spread" creates a new column for each value of the "names" column, with the corresponding values. The last bit (mutate_at) converts back prices to numeric format.